# Pytorch pruning on LSTM increases model size?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, lstm, pruning

I am applying pruning using pytorch's `torch.nn.utils.prune` on a model with LSTM layers. However, when I save the contents of the `state_dict`, the model is much larger than before pruning. I'm not sure why, as if I print out the sizes of the elements of the `state_dict` before and after pruning, everything is the same dimension, and there are no additional elements in the `state_dict`.

My code for pruning is pretty standard, and I make sure to call `prune.remove()`:

```
        model_state = model.state_dict()
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'pre_pruning.pth')
        for param_tensor in model_state:
            print(param_tensor, "\t", model_state[param_tensor].size())

        parameters_to_prune = []
        for param, _ in model.rnn.named_parameters():
            if "weight" in param:
                parameters_to_prune.append((model.rnn, param))
        prune.global_unstructured(parameters_to_prune, pruning_method=prune.L1Unstructured, amount=0.6)
        for module, param in parameters_to_prune:
            prune.remove(module, param)

        model_state = model.state_dict()
        torch.save(model_state, 'pruned.pth') # This file is much larger than the original
        for param_tensor in model_state:
            print(param_tensor, "\t", model_state[param_tensor].size())
```

When I have tried to prune the linear layers in the model, the saved model does not show the same increase in size as when I prune the LSTM layers. Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because pruning introduces two new parameters `weight_orig` and `weight_mask` which essentially increases the model size.

If you wish to remove those parameters, you should use `torch.nn.utils.prune.remove()` to remove them and stops the pruning process (meaning the zeroed weights will not be frozen after this step).

Check [Pruning Tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/pruning_tutorial.html) for details.